# How to develop a many value logic system into Prolog? Which meta interpreter is needed?

Tags: prolog, logic, computer-science

Let's suppose we have to manage an inconsistent database, and in the system we want to develop we do have 4 truth values ( T,F, Both, None). Where, given a P formula we do have:

- A) The computer is told that P is true (and is not told that is False).
- B)The computer is told that P is false ( and is not told that is True).
- C)The computer is told that P is both true and false(e.g.different  sources)
- D)The computer is not told anything about P.

So, I evalute my truth table, and set up different booleian operator as different truth values, e.g. if we name "neq" the negation function into this system,  we could write down the 4-values, like :

- neq(none,none)
- neq(F,T)
- neq(T,F)
- neq(both,both)
- List item

And so for all others operator; Then I need set up the definitions semantically:

1. *At least true under v* if v(A)= T or v(A)=Both
2. *Non true under v* if v(A)=T or v(A)=Both
3. *At least false under v* if v(A)= F or v(A)=none
4. *Non false under v* if v(A)=F or V(A)= Both

How to develop all that into prolog, which meta interprete I should use? thanks

Comment: I expect this already exists: I once attended a talk about someone doing more or less this. He said that this is how Japanese people look to logic: that something can be *both* true and false, or *not* true and false at all.

Comment: This might be relevant: "MUltlog is a system which takes as input the specification of a finitely-valued first-order logic and produces a sequent calculus, a natural deduction system, and clause formation rules for this logic." https://www.logic.at/multlog/ and https://www.logic.at/multseq/. These systems are written in Prolog.